# import SQL data into Dataframe - provide column types?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to provide a dictionary of column types when using Pandas "read_sql_query"? Something like the equivalent of converters for "read_csv"

Comment: By Default it will use the same data type specified in your table. If you want to change the dtype you could do after converting to dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply my own column formats, after importing SQL data using pandas: read_sql_query, I did: (column_1 is string and column_2 is Decimal)

```
 import decimal
 import pandas as pd
 types = {column_1: str, column_2: lambda x: decimal.Decimal(x)}
 df = pd.Dataframe({'column_1': ["a", "b"], 'column_2': [3.141, 2.718]}
 for column in df.columns:
     df[column] = df[column].apply(types[column])
```